# How to hard-wire CC and CC2 pins for a hard-wired device?

Tags: usb, usb-device, usb-hub

I am designing a board with a Microchip [USB7252](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/usb7252) hub IC and a superspeed device. The superspeed device is wired directly into Port 1 of the USB7252. Port 1 is designed to be wired to a Type-C connector, and so uses CC and CC2 pins to detect the orientation of the Type-C connector.

However, I am not wiring it to a connector. Instead I'm wiring it directly to a superspeed device, which obviously is not reversible.

How should I configure the CC and CC2 pins of Port 1 so that it no longer acts as a reversible Type-C connector, but instead keeps a fixed orientation to connect to this superspeed device?

Answer (score 1):

Typically you should contact MCHP/SMSC field application engineer with this kind of questions. Also, they used to have free review of customer's schematics, to avoid typical major screwups on their side.

In general for Type-C hardwire, you pick the PHY you want to use with your device, and pull down the corresponding CC pin with 5.1k. And leave the other PHY and CC pin alone.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. You mean if I want to use PHY1, I should pull CC1 low. And if I want to use PHY2, I should pull CC2 low ?

Comment: Most likely the mapping is as you say. There should be application notes and reference schematics for general Type-C connector. You need to figure out which side of CC1 or CC2 activates corresponding PHY, A or B. I would put two sets of pads for 5.1k pull-downs on a first test PCB.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet Note that you might need to pull both wires low, one via a 5.1K resistor, and the other via a 1K or lower, for the chip that would be on a valid cable (as USB 3.0 C cables have a marked chip that says the cable is capable of carrying USB 3.0 traffic)